# Why is an iframe in XUL popup not displayed?

Tags: iframe, firefox-addon, xul

I'm trying to create addon for Firefox that will play on-line radio. I need to dispaly an iframe with radio player.

When I put this directly into the XUL document, everything is fine. The iframe is loaded and displayed:

```xml
<iframe src="http://player.radiocafe.centrum.cz/back90s/" width="300" height="400" />
```

But when I try to put it inside a popup, the iframe is loaded (it takes space, the radio is playing, I can manipulate the iframe via JavaScript, etc.), but it's content is not displayed:

```xml
<toolbarbutton label="Radio test" class="ch-styled" popup="ch-radioTest" />
<panel id="ch-radioTest" position="after_start">
    <iframe src="http://player.radiocafe.centrum.cz/back90s/" width="300" height="400" />
</panel>
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong? Is it even possible? If not, why?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the frame displays fine - if you make it wider you will see that the web page is being displayed. Merely the radio player (which is a Flash object) is invisible. That looks like a platform limitation/bug - I guess that Gecko cannot correctly determine the area where the plugin should draw. You can file a bug about that on [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/) but I consider the chances rather slim. It's more likely that you will have to find a work-around for this (like using a borderless dialog window instead of a panel).

Side-notes:

- You should add `type="content"` attribute on your panel. Otherwise you give it access to the browser's chrome, already code like `top.location = "http://google.com/"` inside that frame would be fatal.
- You should set the `src` attribute of the frame dynamically when the panel opens and remove it again when it closes. Since the frame is inside the browser window, it will load when it first becomes visible - and it will not unload until the browser window is closed. So the music will keep playing even when the panel is already closed.

Comment: Thank you. I tought it's a bug, but I could not find any confirmation. I'm adding the IFRAME dynamicaly in my code. I also have all the other attributes there. I just wanted to show the cleanest possible example here, to prevent confusion.